# Group by and grouping functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created a view that have 3 columns: service_id, professional_id and avg(rating), and this view is working fine.

```
CREATE VIEW nota_profissionais 
AS 
    SELECT 
        service_id, professional_id, avg(nota) AS nota_media 
    FROM 
        avaliacao, servico_executado, solicitacao 
    WHERE 
        avaliacao.service_id = servico_executado.id 
        AND servico_executado.id_solicitacao = solicitacao.id
    GROUP BY 
        service_id, professional_id;
```

Now, for each `service_id` it returns (each type of service), I need to show the professional which has the best average rating. I tried doing this:

```
SELECT 
    service_id, professional_id, MAX(nota_media) AS nota_media 
FROM 
    nota_profissionais 
GROUP BY 
    service_id, professional_id;
```

But it returns the exact same thing from the view, showing every professional_id per service_id. I know why that's happening, but don't know to how to do this query correctly. Sorry if I'm not being clear, as English isn't my native language.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read, and easier to convert to outer join (if needed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a `LATERAL` subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT service_id FROM nota_profissionais) t1,
    LATERAL (SELECT professional_id, nota_media
             FROM nota_profissionais
             WHERE service_id=t1.service_id
             ORDER BY nota_media DESC LIMIT 1) t2
```

This will find all distinct `service_id`s (first subquery) and then for each one of them, it will find a the best professional (second subquery, the one with `LATERAL`).

If you have a lot of data, make sure that you have an index on `(service_id, nota_media DESC)`.

Comment: Don't LATERAL JOINS have to "re-run" the query for each item in the FROM?  Seems like this would be much slower than a windowing solution, but I don't have a DB to test with.  Very cute trick tho.

Comment: Thanks for the aswer, it did the trick. I'll look up for the documentation of lateral join.

Comment: @S.Costa I had forgotten a condition, can you retry now?

Comment: @Hogan I have actually found that the opposite is true, more so when the the groups are large. The reason is that with this approach, for every `service_id` it will have to find the best professional and it can do that with a simple index lookup, whereas with the `row_number` approach it will assign numbers to all members of each group only to discard most of them later on.

Comment: @redneb - I guess it depends on the compiler, I've see them optimize to what you describe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a windowing function to do this:

```
SELECT service_id, professional_id, nota_media,
FROM (
  SELECT service_id, professional_id, nota_media,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY service_id ORDER BY nota_media DESC) as RN
) x
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (service_id) np.*
FROM nota_profissionais np
ORDER BY service_id, nota_media DESC;
```

Not only is the shortest in query length, but `DISTINCT ON` often has better performance in comparison to other methods.

Answer (score 0):

If there are several professionals with the same best rating and you want to get all of them, not only the first random:

```
select t.*
from nota_profissionais t
  join (
    select service_id, max(nota_media) as nota_media 
    from nota_profissionais
    group by service_id) t1 
  on (t.service_id = t1.service_id and t.nota_media = t1.nota_media)
```

Actually the same result should return the @Hogan's answer if change the `ROW_NUMBER()` to the `RANK()` function.